# Android Nav graph check has deeplink without navHostFragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I need to check if an nav graph has deeplink and NavGraph provides hasDeeplink() method that I want to use. But I need this information outside activity or fragment. Is there any way to init NavGraph with navigation id resource outside fragment/activity?

I tried some options to get NavGraph instance but every ends with an exception.

Thanks